# React Native - Conditionally render views

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, mobx

I have a react native app that I'm working on. Right now I want it to have two views. A login page and the main page. It so far looks like this:

**index.ios.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Dimensions,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  Button,
  TouchableHighlight,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import Scanner from './app/components/Scanner';
import Login from './app/components/Login';
import Store from './app/mobx/store';

export default class TestApp extends Component {
  render() {
    if (Store.loggedIn()){
      return <Scanner />
    } else {
      return <Login store={Store} />
    }
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: '#114DA0'
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('TestApp', () => TestApp);
```

**app/components/Login.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  ScrollView
} from 'react-native';
import Container from './Container';
import Button from './Button';
import Label from './Label';
import {observer} from 'mobx-react/native';

@observer
export default class Login extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      isLoggingIn: false,
      message: ''
    }
    this._userLogin = this._userLogin.bind(this);
  }
  _userLogin() {
    console.log("loggin in...")
    this.setState({isLoggingIn: true, message:''});
    var params = {
        email: this.state.email,
        password: this.state.password
    };
    var formBody = [];
    for (var property in params) {
      var encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(property);
      var encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(params[property]);
      formBody.push(encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue);
    }
    formBody = formBody.join("&");
    fetch("http://example.com:8000/auth/mobile_login", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        body: formBody
      })
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json()
      })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.error) {
          this.setState({message: response.message});
        } else if (response.user) {
          this.props.store.logIn(response.user);
        }
      })
      .then(() => {
        this.setState({isLoggingIn: false})
      })
      .done();
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <ScrollView style={styles.scroll}>
          <Container>
            <Label text="Email" />
            <TextInput
              style={styles.textInput}
              onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({email})}
            />
          </Container>
          <Container>
            <Label text="Password" />
            <TextInput
              secureTextEntry={true}
              style={styles.textInput}
              onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password})}
            />
          </Container>
          <Container>
            {!!this.state.message && (
              <Text style={{fontSize: 14, color: 'red', padding: 5}}>
                {this.state.message}
              </Text>
            )}
            <Button
              label="Sign In"
              styles={{button: styles.primaryButton, label: styles.buttonWhiteText}}
              onPress={this._userLogin} />
          </Container>
        </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  ...
});
```

**app/components/Scanner.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Dimensions,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableHighlight,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import Camera from 'react-native-camera';

export default class Scanner extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.onBarCodeRead = this.onBarCodeRead.bind(this);
  }
  onBarCodeRead(e) {
    this.setState({text: e.data});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <Camera
            ref={(cam) => {
              this.camera = cam;
            }}
            onBarCodeRead={this.onBarCodeRead}
            style={styles.preview}
            aspect={Camera.constants.Aspect.fill}>
          </Camera>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  ...
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Scanner', () => Scanner);
```

Both pages work fine and I am able to login to my service through the login page. But once I log in, how can I get the root component to render the Scanner page?

Answer (score 0):

The key here is that render is called each time a call to setState is made:

> Performs a shallow merge of nextState into current state. This is the
>   primary method you use to trigger UI updates from event handlers and
>   server request callbacks.
>   https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate

So updating a component's content based on state change (in this case, user logging in) can be achieved by checking this loggedIn state and conditionally rendering the content.

Consider the following code as an example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';


const ContentA = () => (
    <div>
        <h1>Filled with content A</h1>
    </div>
);

const ContentB = () => (
    <div>
        <h1>Filled with content B</h1>
    </div>
);


class App extends Component {

    state = {
        loggedIn: false
    };

    logIn = () => {
        this.setState({
            loggedIn: !this.state.loggedIn
        })
    };

    render() {

    const content = this.state.loggedIn ? <ContentA/> : <ContentB/>;
    return (
        <div>
            {content}
            <button onClick={this.logIn}>Clicky</button>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Each time the button is clicked, a call to setState is made, and the component re-renders based on the value of this.state.loggedIn.

Hope this helps, and good luck!